# Can Azure Monitor call an external API such that alerts can be broadcasted to external API's?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Folks, I could not find from going through the Azure Monitor documentation whether it is possible for Azure Monitor to make an REST API call to an external API such that the alerts themselves(Not Notifications) captured by Azure Monitor can be broadcasted to external API's.

I do find that Azure Monitor exposes REST API's which are more of a pull scenario. But i am looking for a push scenario where Azure Monitor can push alerts (not notifications)

any pointers should be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create alerts with action groups and specify the action type as Webhook and then provide the URI to your API endpoint.

Comment: is there any channel or RSS feed or Queue or Topic to which Azure publishes such alerts? or can we create such a subscription model to listen for alerts?

Comment: You can create your individual alerts and then configure multiple action groups to push alerts to multiple channels such as email, SMS, API, Azure Functions, Azure Event Grid, etc.